# Receive map interface instead of struct

Tags: go

I am passing a value through function which can be different struct type based on some condition.
The caller and receiving function is in different go file.
I am expecting the value in receiving file like:

```
{Jhon Teacher 33 science}
```

but getting

```
map[Name:Jhon Teacher  Age:33 Department:science]
```

Source:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// Student payload format
type Student struct {
    Name  string
    Age   int
    Class int
}

// Teacher payload format
type Teacher struct {
    Name       string
    Age        int
    Department string
}

func activity(resp interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(resp)
    switch resp.(type) {
    case Student:
        fmt.Println("activity here Student")
    case Teacher:
        fmt.Println("activity here Teacher")
    default:
        fmt.Println("activity here defaultNotification")
    }
}

func main() {
    var notification interface{}
    if false {
        notification = Student{
            Name:  "Jhon doe",
            Age:   23,
            Class: 10,
        }
    } else {
        notification = Teacher{
            Name:       "Jhon Teacher",
            Age:        33,
            Department: "science",
        }
    }
    activity(notification)
}
```

Note: The above code is just a dummy that I have tried (working fine in playground), where the `activity()` function is in different go file and the struct are also different with many fields.

How I can get the struct type from the `interface{} (map[Name:Jhon Teacher  Age:33 Department:science])`.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a map into a struct?

Comment: What is the type of the map? Is it `map[string]string`? Or `map[string]interface{}`? And, did you get the map from json? If yes why not unmarshal the json directly into the struct?

Comment: @mkoprive, it is map[string]interface{}, and firstly i need to verify the struct type from the response as i can get multiple type (e.g Student, Teacher etc), then i can convert it.
switch resp.(type) does not give me the struct type always going to the default case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Also showing working code in your question does not help anyone to better understand the problem you are trying to solve. Please consider providing a [mcve].

Comment: Atleast you have to add identifiable field for those structs to do that. In your case `_, ok := mapName["Department"]` then if it is okay, the it is a teacher, otherwise student.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// Student payload format
type Student struct {
    Name  string
    Age   int
    Class int
}

// Teacher payload format
type Teacher struct {
    Name       string
    Age        int
    Department string
}

func activity(resp map[string]interface{}) {
    for _, v := range resp {
        switch v.(type) {
        case Student:
            fmt.Println("activity here Student")
        case Teacher:
            fmt.Println("activity here Teacher")
        default:
            fmt.Println("activity here defaultNotification")
        }

    }
}

func main() {
    notificationMap := map[string]interface{}{
        "1": Student{
            Name:  "Jhon doe",
            Age:   23,
            Class: 10,
        },
        "2": Teacher{
            Name:       "Jhon Teacher",
            Age:        33,
            Department: "science",
        },
    }

    activity(notificationMap)
}
```

Comment: you could print the missed type in the default case of the switch with `fmt.Printf("activity kind %T not recognized\n", resp)`

Comment: @mh-cbon Ofcourse, that could be the value addition.